# How to assign a style to a newly added paragraph in Word Add-in

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-addins

I have a problem inserting a paragraph and immediately changing its style. It seems like a simple task, but it always returns RichApi.Error: Invalid argument. I want to create a new chapter at the cursor position, that means to add a new paragraph and apply style "Heading2" to it. Any ideas what could be wrong with the code? I also tried to call context.sync() right after creating the new paragraph but the result was the same. Thanks.

EDIT: I just found out it doesn't work if you insert the paragraph on Range object. It only works if I call insertParagraph on context.document.body. If I insert it into context.document.getSelection(), which returns a Range object, it doesn't! What if I want to insert a new chapter at the cursor position, in the middle of the document, not at the end of it? It looks like another bug of the library unfortunately.

```
  const handleInsertChapter = async () => {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const selection = context.document.getSelection();

    const chapter = selection.insertParagraph("New paragraph", "After");
    chapter.styleBuiltIn = "Heading2";

    await context.sync();
  }).catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
```

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, please report it as an issue in the Office-js repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=

Comment: Thanks, Rick. I already did. Hopefully your colleagues will have a look at it soon.